# How to have image floating 2 columns right after text with ieeeconf

Tags: graphics, ieeeconf

I have researched and I tried a few things in order to achieve the same thing as the attached picture show with \documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf} but still could not have it done.

I tried the combination with [h], [!], [H] but none of them worked

Currently, I have the image floating 2 columns but my image is put to the last page of the document.

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.085]{figure/HD01.JPG}
\caption{ Experimental Setup }
\label{fg:v1}
\end{figure*}
```

**Working Example:**

[image]

Comment: You can try the `split` environment from `cuted` (it's a non-float environment, and use `\captionof[figure]{Some caption}\label{some label}` from the `caption` package.

Comment: Not sure it is because that I both have `amsmath` and `cuted`, I have some trouble to make it work. Can you show an example how to use the `split`, I tried and it returned `Package amsmath Error: \begin{split} won't work here. \end{split}`

Comment: Sorry;, I miswrote it: it is the `strip` environment, which has nothing to do with maths. I should have reread my comment before posting…

Comment: I fount a solution close to your request... but is just a solution if you don't find other way... I think it will work for you, but I leaving my first answer that I think fits to less experienced users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New workaround... but it is has "manual" fixing of  the spaces and so it is not suggested... I just writing another answer to have it as a last solution if you will not find a better way.... it works on twocolumn articles, so I suppose it will work for you too... But use it after you have finished everything in the the chapter (or one known starting newpage)... else you will fixing again and again the spaces during  your work progress...

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Single column

Like TeX, LaTeX started as a writing tool for mathematicians and computer scientists, but from early in its development it has 



\section{Second section}

Twocolums section

LaTeX can be arbitrarily extended by using the underlying macro language to develop custom formats. Such macros are often 
collected into packages, which are available to address special formatting issues such as complicated mathematical content or graphics.
Indeed, in the example below, the align environment is provided by the amsmath package.

Breaking Twocolums in this place





%\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}


\hspace*{130pt}\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Longpic.png}
  \caption{This is a figure caption}
\end{figure}



\end{minipage}

\end{@twocolumnfalse}
  %]



Going back to Twocolums

\LaTeX{} is a document preparation system for
  the \TeX{} typesetting program. It offers
  programmable desktop publishing features and
  extensive facilities for automating most
  aspects of typesetting and desktop publishing,
  including numbering and  cross-referencing,
  tables and figures, page layout,
  bibliographies, and much more. \LaTeX{} was
  originally written in 1984 by Leslie Lamport
  and has become the  dominant method for using
  \TeX; few people write in plain \TeX{} anymore.
  The current version is \LaTeXe.


LaTeX can be arbitrarily extended by using the underlying macro language to develop custom formats. Such macros are often 
collected into packages, which are available to address special formatting issues such as complicated mathematical content or graphics.
Indeed, in the example below, the align environment is provided by the amsmath package.

LaTeX can be arbitrarily extended by using the underlying macro language to develop custom formats. Such macros are often 
collected into packages, which are available to address special formatting issues such as complicated mathematical content or graphics.
Indeed, in the example below, the align environment is provided by the amsmath package.


LaTeX can be arbitrarily extended by using the underlying macro language to develop custom formats. Such macros are often 
collected into packages, which are available to address special formatting issues such as complicated mathematical content or graphics.
Indeed, in the example below, the align environment is provided by the amsmath package.

LaTeX can be arbitrarily extended by using the underlying macro language to develop custom formats.\vspace*{155pt}


Such macros are often 
collected into packages, which are available to address special formatting issues 
such as complicated mathematical content or graphics.
Indeed, in the example below, the align environment is provided by the amsmath package.


\end{document}
```

And the result continues as the photo of your request (continues on the first column and then goes to the second).

See it:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try compination of 'multicol' package with 'float'... See my example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Single column

Like TeX, LaTeX started as a writing tool for mathematicians and computer scientists, but from early in its development it has 
also been taken up by scholars who needed to write documents that include complex math expressions or non-Latin scripts, 
such as Arabic, Sanskrit and Chinese[citation needed].

LaTeX is intended to provide a high-level language that accesses the power of TeX in an easier way for writers. In short,
TeX handles the layout side, while LaTeX handles the content side for document processing. LaTeX comprises a collection 
of TeX macros and a program to process LaTeX documents. Because the plain TeX formatting commands are elementary,
it provides authors with ready-made commands for formatting and layout requirements such as chapter headings, footnotes,
cross-references and bibliographies.


\section{Second section}

\begin{multicols}{2}
Twocolums section

LaTeX can be arbitrarily extended by using the underlying macro language to develop custom formats. Such macros are often 
collected into packages, which are available to address special formatting issues such as complicated mathematical content or graphics.
Indeed, in the example below, the align environment is provided by the amsmath package.

Breaking Twocolums in this place

\end{multicols}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Sc1.png}
  \caption{This is a figure caption}
\end{figure}


\begin{multicols}{2}

Going back to Twocolums

\LaTeX{} is a document preparation system for
  the \TeX{} typesetting program. It offers
  programmable desktop publishing features and
  extensive facilities for automating most
  aspects of typesetting and desktop publishing,
  including numbering and  cross-referencing,
  tables and figures, page layout,
  bibliographies, and much more. \LaTeX{} was
  originally written in 1984 by Leslie Lamport
  and has become the  dominant method for using
  \TeX; few people write in plain \TeX{} anymore.
  The current version is \LaTeXe.
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

And here is the result:
[image]

Comment: I am not sure if because the `\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}` is already 2 columns format so when I add the `\begin{multicols}{2}` and \end{multicols}{2}`, it does not create the pdf.  The program (TeXstudio) just stuck.

Comment: Sorry... maybe a workaround is to give '\onecolumn' before start multicols... Sorry but I don't have ieeeconf... Good luck!

Comment: Thanks koleygr & Bernard for the help.  I will try some of the combinations to see if I can have it worked.